# Content Security Policy in .htaccess or with meta tag?

Tags: .htaccess, content-security-policy, http-equiv

## Context

I have a [VueJs](https://vuejs.org/) single page application (in really just one HTML file), that I want to apply [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) to. This is hosted on a subdomain, served from a shared host, and I can create `.htaccess` files there.

As far as I understand I have two options:

- put the CSP directive in the HTTP headers using for example the apache server's `.htaccess` file (like e.g. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70031065/79485))
- add the CSP via `meta http-equiv` (like e.g. [in this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#using_the_html_meta_element))

Seemingly, I can also mix the two.

## Question

However, **is there a difference between HTTP headers (using`.htaccess`) and `meta http-equiv`** in terms of

- safety (could allowed scripts e.g. manipulate the html headers further)
- [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#browser_compatibility)
- other implications

Comment: The first option is not a ".htaccess" option. It uses the apache headers module to add a http header to the response. Where you implement that, in the http server's configuration, at scripting level or in a distributed configuration file is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha for this hint, I updated the question in this regard. Actually the point is not so much the server in use, but the fact that it's in the HTTP headers. I hope my update reflects that.

Comment: Yes, actually it's the one I already refer to in my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53095698/79485) by @sideshowbarker, the specs require browsers to ignore some of the CSP directives in the meta-tag, namely:

- Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only
- report-uri
- frame-ancestors
- sandbox

Also the directives in the HTML `meta http-equiv` tag only apply to content/links/includes after the tag.

Per the above spec, however, manipulation is not possible once the tag has been processed:

> Modifications to the content attribute of a meta element after the
> element has been parsed will be ignored.

## Conclusion

In the end, it seems to be **most safe to stick to HTTP headers**, if possible.